# How do you make Custom Listview rows in baseadapter clickable?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I'm having a heck of a time making rows from a custom list view made with a baseadapter clickable. Currently, they can be clicked, but an error ensues and the app crashes..

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED

**Here is the main activity which includes the custom adapter that extends a baseadapter**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(new HalsAdapter(this));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    class SingleRow {
        String title;
        String description;
        int image;
        SingleRow(String title, String description, int image) {
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.image = image;
        }
    }
    class HalsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList < SingleRow > list;
        Context context;
        HalsAdapter(Context c) {

            context = c;
            list = new ArrayList < SingleRow > ();

            Resources res = c.getResources();
            String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
            String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
            int[] images = {
                R.drawable.placeholder1, R.drawable.placeholder2, R.drawable.placeholder3, R.drawable.placeholder4, R.drawable.placeholder5, R.drawable.placeholder6, R.drawable.placeholder7, R.drawable.placeholder8, R.drawable.placeholder9, R.drawable.placeholder10, R.drawable.placeholder11, R.drawable.placeholder12, R.drawable.placeholder13, R.drawable.placeholder14, R.drawable.placeholder15
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i]));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }@Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return list.get(i);
        }@Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }@Override public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            LayoutInflater inflater(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);

            TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
            title.setText(temp.title);
            description.setText(temp.description);
            image.setImageResource(temp.image);

            return row;
        }
    }@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(homeScreen.this, privateSpaceList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;


    }
}
```

**Here is single_row.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/placeholder1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
android:text="Large Text"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="Small Text"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

I left the onitemclick empty because my methods were not working and the mainactivity doesn't like me to call the other method of onitemclick.

I created an activity called ListItemActivity I would like the onclick to call, in turn the listitemactivity calls a test.xml page. I have been stuck for a few days trying to figure out how to make the custom rows clickable.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your layout `single_row` . Are you using checkbox in the layout?

Comment: I added the code Above to onsiteclick that gives error on click in any row of listview.  The app simply crashes when I click on any row in listview. Also going to post single row layout.

Comment: No checkbox in the layout Libin

Comment: Your list item rows are already clickable because of the `list.setOnItemClickListener(this);` line. When you get a crash, the first thing you do is go to Logcat and find the stack trace. If you don't know how to interpret the stack trace, post it here and someone will help you.

Comment: The error seems to have something to do with not defining ListViewActivity class in MainActiviy?

Comment: @user3606168 does imageview take focus when you click on list item?

Comment: Thank you so much Karakuri, I checked Logcat and found the problem!! I didn't have ListViewActivity in Android Manifest and I needed to change Listview ID to list. Also needed to change extends ListActivity in ListViewActivity.java to extend Activity. Clicking now brings me to test.xml Now I just need to figure out how to make each row go to a corresponding xml page separately because they all go to test.xml I defined in ListActivityItem so far!! Thanks again!